# How to make <textarea> use rest of the height available

Tags: html, css, height, textarea, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a "chat window", I have most things sorted out but somehow I can't get the "conversation" textarea to occupy the rest of the window vertically.

Here is my full page code (the textarea I want to adjust is the one inside the `div id="conversation"`):

```
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">

<title>
chat prototype
</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="completeSite" style="display: flex; flex-flow:row wrap" >

<div id="taskBar" class="col-md-12" style="border-style: solid; ">
TASKBAR
</div>
<div id="userList" class="col-md-2" style="border-style: solid;">
USERLIST
</div>

<div id="chatWindow" class="col-md-10" style="border-style:solid;">

<div id="conversation" class="row">
<textarea readonly class="form-control"  style="overflow:auto; resize:none; border-style: solid;">CONVERSATION</textarea>
</div>

<div id="MessageInput" class="input-group row">
<textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Message" style="height: 200px; overflow:auto; resize:none;"></textarea>

<span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn" id="submitMessageButton" type="button" style="height: 200px; background-color:  #999999">Send</button>
</span>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Every piece of css that is not bootstrap is individually in the elements using `style=`.

So far I've tried some things:

1. Relative `height:` definition, but that gives undesirable results when the window is minimized (it keeps the size according to the screen size and not to the window size).
2. Flex approach: placed `display:flex; flex-direction:column` on the `div id=conversation` and afterwards on the `div id=chatWindow` always using `flex: 1` on the textarea, but with no results. I saw this solution on some other question from Stack Overflow, so decided to try it out obviously.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this "but that gives undiserable results when the window is minimized (it keeps the size according to the screen size and not to the window size)."? Mainly, what is difference between window and screen.

Comment: So, my screen can be 1920x1080 but I may have my window occupying only a small part of that screen (like when not maximized).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign your window height to your chat box height. Add your own code id or class name instead of "#myDiv".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(window).outerHeight();
    $('#myDiv').css('min-height', windowHeight);
  };
  setHeight();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight();
  });
});
```

For more see this link:[ViewPort](https://j.eremy.net/set-element-height-to-viewport/)

Comment: Thanks, this works. Just the resize part is not working (edge and chrome). Trying to investigate why.

Comment: Test this demo: https://codepen.io/jeremychurch/full/qaIbK, on chrome and edge, if this demo is working its means you need to check css properties at your code or some inline style. For more: https://j.eremy.net/set-element-height-to-viewport/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the answer from "user123" was mostly correct but, in terms of browser compatibility it was giving me problems due to `$(window).innerHeight();`
Which, according to the w3schools description is "the inner height of a window's content area"

However, this was only working on Edge and IE11. To get it working on Edge, IE11, Firefox and Chrome I had to use `$(window).outerHeight();`. 
Which is described at w3schools as being "the outer height of a window, including toolbars/scrollbars"

Bottom-line: In terms of "sense", it makes none of it but I got it working using the outerHeight() instead of the innerHeight() function.

PS:Posted as an answer to call attention.